# Table Comment missing on Azure Delta Table

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have created a delta table in azure databricks with COMMENT as below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbtest.test_antony;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbtest.test_antony(
  db_name STRING COMMENT 'EN: Database Name ',
  table_name STRING COMMENT 'EN: Table Name '
)
USING delta
LOCATION 'dbfs:/mnt/user/antony/test_antony'
COMMENT 'my test table'
```

I tried to take extract of this table by using below comments, but no where I could see the table comment **'my test table'**.

```
describe dbtest.test_antony;
describe detail dbtest.test_antony;
describe table formatted dbtest.test_antony;
describe table extended dbtest.test_antony;
```

[image]

Also when I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` I am not able to see **COMMENT** for the table.
I tried with cluster versions 10.4 and 11.2

How Could I get the table comment in table extract ? Any leads appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, maybe it's dependent on the Databricks Runtime version and/or on the Hive metastore version (if you're not using built-in metastore).

Your code works perfectly for me on DBR 11.1, and `describe table extended` returns `Comment` row as well

[image]

Comment: We are using built in metastore and we are using cluster version 10.4.  But I tried with cluster version 11.2 and still COMMENT is not available for tables.

Comment: Is there any other chance for omitting the table comment?

Comment: I'm not aware about such thing...

Comment: Alex, Could you please let me know the table properties returned when you run describe table command?

Comment: `[delta.minReaderVersion=1,delta.minWriterVersion=2]` Are you using external Hive metastore? If yes, maybe metastore version doesn't support comments on tables?